# Why does my button does not display set style?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I try to change the style of my button but it simply does not display the set style. It only shows the 'default' rectangle styling. I read the "Style and Themes" official android documentation and the issue is not about style hierarchy. Here is my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Button.Toggle"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="155dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.74" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and my styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

I also set the content view with the layout file above in my onCreate() function. It is as if the @android:style ressource couldn't be found? Please help

I also ran clean project and got

```
W/ResourceType(15056): For resource 0x0101053d, entry index(1341) is beyond 
type entryCount(1320)
W/ResourceType(15056): For resource 0x0101053e, entry index(1342) is beyond 
type entryCount(1320)
W/ResourceType(15056): For resource 0x0101053b, entry index(1339) is beyond 
type entryCount(1320)
W/ResourceType(15056): For resource 0x0101053c, entry index(1340) is beyond 
type entryCount(1320)
```

Comment: What do you expect to see compared to the default style? And what does the Button actually look like?

Comment: @0X0nosugar I expect to see a toggle button instead of a rectangle

Comment: Hey if you want toggle button then why you are using button view ,Android provide toggle /switch for this kind of functionality.You can customise that toggle view too.

Comment: @vishvakapadia the issue is not about the toggle button only, any button style that I set, I don't see a difference in the look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In res/values/styles.xml you need to define a button style such as 'MyButtonStyle'

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>

<style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button</item>
</style>
```

In res/drawable/button.xml you define the baseline style for your button which is defined as a selector referencing pressed and default states such as.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal"/>
</selector>
```

In res/drawable/button_normal

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
<stroke android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/buttonDarkShade"/>
<gradient
    android:type="linear"
    android:angle="90"
    android:startColor="@color/buttonDarkShade"
    android:centerColor="@color/buttonHighlightShade"
    android:endColor="@color/buttonDarkShade"
    />
</shape>
```

In res/drawable/button_pressed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">

<stroke android:width="4dp"
        android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark"/>
<gradient
    android:type="linear"
    android:angle="90"
    android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:centerColor="@color/buttonHighlightShade"
    android:endColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    />
<corners android:radius="16dp" />
</shape>
```

This is the basic template for making a custom button. Define the res/values/colors used above and change or add selector and shape attributes as you want.

and of course when you use the button style in a layout remember to set the style

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/myCustomStylishButton"
    style="@style/MyButtonStyle"/>
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer but this does not answer my question; Let me clarify some stuff, when I change the style attribute of a button I insert in the layout editor I do not see a change in its style when I boot the app

Comment: Does removing the android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light" allow you to see style changes?

Answer (score 0):

I found the [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/gingerbread-release/core/res/res/values/styles.xml) containing the style "Widget.Button.Toggle". It seems to be an old style, I suppose it's not possible to use it with an AppCompat app theme.

One reason why I think so is because the linked repo has the name "gingerbread" in its path, the other reason is that my Android Studio (3.3) does not know the style - if I try to use it the text turns red.

But you said that you can't successfully apply any style whatsoever. So I copied your code snippets into my sample app and did the following:

**Step 1** Declare a style in *res/values/styles.xml* and try to use it with the `Button`:

```
<style name="MyButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00ff00</item>
</style>
```

In  *activity_main.xml*

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    style="@style/MyButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="155dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.74"
    android:text="Hello World"/>
```

Result:

[image]

**Step 2** Use a known AppCompat style with the `Button`, for example `Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored`. (I kept the background simply to show that it works, even if a borderless `Button` with a background sounds a bit paradoxical)

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="155dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.74"
    android:text="Hello World"/>
```

Result:

[image]

**Step 3** (even more optional than the other two) Pick some AppCompat `Button` style, try to make it work and get back here if you run into an error.

(General advice: update Android Studio to a current stable version if necessary and make sure you don't mix AndroidX libraries and support libraries in the dependencies closure in the module's *build.gradle* file)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the answers but I found that what I was looking for was to add the ImageButton widget to my xml sheet in contrast to the Button widget